# Is there an easy way to find what function is calling another function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm not too well-versed in Python, although, I think this question is mostly language-agnostic, but wanted to see if there was a particular way to do it for Python.

I'm working with a couple of Pytorch Python scripts.

The function `test_qtensor_cpu` on line 147 in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fbcode/warm/test/quantization/core/test_quantized_tensor.py is being executed when I run the script in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fbcode/warm/test/test_quantization.py, but I cannot find the function that calls `test_qtensor_cpu`. I did a `grep -ri "test_qtensor_cpu*" .` in the root director of this repo and the only result was the definition of this function.

Is there a way for this function to be called without explicitly writing out the function's name?

Comment: why not run with a debugger, have a breakpoint on `test_qtensor_cpu` and look at the call stack?

Comment: @Nullman Embarassingly, I haven't really used a debugger, but I'll try that right now and see if I can figure it out. I just started using VSCode as an IDE, which I believe has a debugger configured for it

Comment: @Nullman Can you answer my other question regarding if it's possible for this function to be executed without explicitly writing out the function's name somewhere in the code?

Comment: @SuperStormer I was thinking something along the lines of `run_tests()` automatically running the suite of test cases as well, but I'm not well versed enough with Python to know how this can be done

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
def my_func_i_cant_figure_out_whats_calling_it()
    import traceback
    traceback.print_stack()
```

That will show you the callstack at that point, even without a breakpoint.

Yes, its possible to call a function without explicitly writing it out.

(and figuring out how to use a debugger is super useful... future you will thank you if you figure it out sooner rather than later)

Answer (score 2):

[Line 29](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fbcode/warm/test/test_quantization.py#L29) of `test_quantization.py` imports `TestQuantizedTensor` (which includes the `test_qtensor_cpu` method).

The `run_tests()` ([source here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fbcode/warm/torch/testing/_internal/common_utils.py#L555)) at the bottom of the file will automatically run all test cases that have been imported (which includes `TestQuantitizedTensor`) via unittest (usually via [`unittest.main`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main), though this can be changed by args passed to the test suite).